# Why do all colors go down at the same speed with laser printer?

Tags: printing, colors, laser-printer, hp-laserjet, toner

I have this suspicious output from my printer (HP M252d)

[image]

I remember printing one large document that had many pages with a layout full of green. I understand that this is not a spot color and that the green in question may have consumed some red and blue, but .. well the pages were green, so I expect the green ink to be much more used.

I guess the display is probably statistical and can't represent the real level, but it looks like it takes all colors, excluding black, and puts the lowest value on all.

Could it be the case? is there a reason for this? (besides trying to get me to buy all colors at once).

Comment: Green is the opposite color of red. Pure green is obtained by mixing blue and yellow in equal parts. So, when printing green, the magenta cartridge is very few sollicitated ; much more are the yellow and cyan cartridges.

Answer (score 1):

Your laser printer is likely doing a rough estimation of the remaining toner, basing on the number of pages printed, and how much toner is consumed with typical inking levels, but ignoring that some colors have been used more than others. This is pure assumption.

Observe the asterisk near "Approximate Pages Remaining", which seems emphasize that this is only an estimate.

One can imagine that a basic logic and simple algorithm is a way to reduce R&D costs.

As a rule, keep in mind that estimated toner levels are not real toner levels, whatever the sophistication of the algorithm.

When a toner is detected as empty, the are often tricks to reset the toner level to full, and make more prints. This depends on brand and model.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you know the opposite to be true, it's quite possible that you've used up the colors at a roughly similar speed - we don't know how exact the "10%" figure is, could be anything from 20 to 5%.

Btw, printer use subtractive colors and green is mixed from yellow and cyan.

Comment: Ah yes, good point, didn’t think of that. I printed a very large amount of pages with a green design, so I should have a bunch of magenta left. I will try to put the toner cartridges on a kitchen scale to see

Answer (score 0):

I worked 6 years for a company in munich and was responsible for the printers.

due the rental change, we got some new devices and had the issue that all pages started to be counted as color pages.

The Original reason was the logo which was used... it had some rgb elements and therefore the printer printed it like that.

so depending on the model and firmware its normal.
Specifically older lexmark and HP ink models have seen this kind of issue

So, verify that the print you sent, have to be in color or select specifically black only. (i. e. grey maybe not grey in real print output, and will be printed with rgb instead of the black)

Comment: So you mean It was just counting pages as H&M’s or color and just apply some count rather than keep track of colors used by each pixels?

Comment: thw main issue is, when some colors look like grey, they arent and will be printed with rgb /cmy instead from thw black toner

Comment: Apparently, the printer says colour was used on 796 pages and guesses that you have 100 pages left. Is this because a colour cartridge is claimed to be good for 900 pages?